# A field that is a multiple of a float field. How?

Tags: 7

Let's say i have a product content type. It has a title, body and price field.

In a view (or in the node page) in addition to these fields I would like to have a multiple of the price field ?

Example :

- Title : Red tshirt
- Body : Tshirt description
- Price : $9,95
- Extra field : $99,5 *( Price x 10 )*

Comment: Do you need to calculate the extra field once and store it in the database, or do you want to calculate it on the fly, every time the node is viewed?

Comment: Prices change. It makes more sense to maintain a single data item than having to maintain two. Calculating it on the fly would have the least maintenance impact.

Comment: @marcvangend I don't know really, i'm still trying to figure this out so i'm looking for ideas and suggestions. Triskelion suggested the Computed Field module so i'll give it a try and see if it does the job.

Comment: Marcellus Wallace: Computed Field is a good module, so I support Triskelion's answer. It offers both options (db-stored and on-the-fly). @Triskelion: I don't quite understand your comment. I know prices change, and I never proposed a solution which involves maintaining two fields. Storing in the db has its advantages, such as using the field data in views as a sort criterion.

Comment: My comment was in response to @marcvangend. And you can always sort by Price.

Comment: I know you were responding to me, that's why I responded to you :-) Anyway, you don't seem to understand what I'm trying to say, but let's not worry about that. I hope the TS got the answer he was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module. Use something like:

```
if ( isset($entity->field_price)){
  $entity_field[0]['value'] = ($entity->field_price[0]['value'] * 10);
}
```

in the Computed Code (PHP) box.